# SSH tunnel with 3 hops

Tags: ssh, centos7, ssh-tunnel

Here What I like to achieve :

windows10(Laptop)->ssh to Jump1 -> ssh Jump2-> ssh to final box(192.168.0.1). my website 192.168.0.2) accessible through  final box

so I want to access the website 192.168.0.2 using ssh tunnel on my laptop.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine on each stage port forwarding, be sure that you don't use port which are used by services using SSH Jumps.
In theory:
putty from laptop, make local forwarding when connect there, this will route port to your laptop, once connected there, do the same on next one, but you need to point to the same port what was used step before.

In theory should work.

https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/tunneling/example

Thanks,